# Java file practice on saving sales and profits data

Tags: java, file-io, load, file-format

I'm trying to create a simple app to be used by small shop owners. I need two sections: one for costs incurred and another for take-ins. What I want is to save these into a file which can later be loaded into the app. When I load the file, I want to display the data in a nice report style, like a table or something. My questions are

1. What is a good format for saving the file? Assume all data to be saved in a single file. Text or XML would do the job but also consider the following question.
2. When saving, how do I avoid saving the whole data into the file again, even though there could only be a couple lines changed from what was loaded?

I know my questions are somewhat general, but I haven't got much experience in file operations, I've used databases before. Also, if you asked what I have tried and looked for, I haven't tried but my first intuition is to save it in one of text or XML format and then load them line by line later. Some guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: *I know my questions are somewhat general, but I haven't got much experience in file operations* start practicing then, you will solve your questions by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the position in the file as you're reading / writing it, so you don't have to rewrite the whole file. For example, using [Reader#skip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#skip(long)). [Suggested reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517367/bufferreader-skip-performance).

Now how do you determine the line for some given element? You'll need some sort of **meta-structure** which allows you to look up the lines for a given element.

Now how do you determine the offset of this line? You need to use **fixed-length** lines, so you can use a simple `line*length`. In this case XML will be total overkill and you generally don't pad XML to fixed length. You could say "Why do we need fixed-length lines? Why not just store the offset of the applicable line rather than the line above?", but you should soon realize that you'll have to update the entire rest of the meta-structure when one line's length changes.

Now all that said, **a database is probably a way better option**. This is exactly what they were made for. Though if you desire to practice your file operations (and this isn't intended to be used in "the real world"), feel free to go ahead.

Comment: I know a database is a better option, but what do you recommend for computers that don't have a database management system installed? Like any average machine used by very casual daily computer users.

Comment: having a java app that can be installed in a few clicks would do the job. people have used programs to save files and then load them later so won't be a burden to have DMBS on their PC

Comment: A DBMS can be installed in a few clicks (and Java programs can be run without installation) and actually all computers should have one installed and programs should use this instead of doing their own little thing. But anyway, that's an ideal-world thing. I'm sure you can find a pure Java implementation of a DBMS (no external installation required), e.g. [SQLJet / sqlite4java (?)](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers) (I only looked at SQLite (which I haven't tried) simply because I thought it did that already (which it doesn't, natively)).

Comment: Actually I looked for something that said "No JDBC" or "Pure Java", which is probably not required - the alternative might only require that you need to copy a DLL or JAR to install, you might not need a DBMS. That said, I'm not really too familiar with Java databases. You may have to look into the Getting Started of a few implementations and see what you need to do, more client-side than development-side.